# Saving or updating data using ef multiple entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have a big problem when I was doing my code which involve insert data, or update if this exists, from a file. I'm using entity framework.
files are near to 16 000 rows

I tried to insert them but I spent a lot of time doing this: more than 5 hour x file.

I decided to change it but i dont know how to start.

I read something about save each 1000, 5000, 10000 row, but I got and exception when i try to do it.

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).
Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh
ObjectStateManager entries.
```

and when I tried to fix it I got this exception

```
AcceptChanges can not continue because the object's key values ​​conflict with another
object in ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values ​​are unique before calling 
AcceptChanges.
```

this is my code

```
//before this I passed db data to lists
foreach (var record in records)
{
    if (record != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_location.Any(s => s.Id.Trim() == record.Id))
            {               
                Location l = new Location
                    {
                        Id = record.Id,
                        Name = record.Name,
                        Address = record.Address,
                        City = record.City,
                        State = record.State,
                        Zip = record.Zip.ToString(),
                        Zip2 = record.Zip2,
                        Custom1 = record.Custom1,                       
                        CreatedDate = date,
                        UpdatedDate = date
                    };

                db.location.Add(l);  
                db.SaveChanges();                              
                _location.Add(l);                                        
            }
            else
            {                                
                if (!_sales.Any(s => s.LocationId == record.Id && s.ReportDate == record.ReportDate))
                {
                    Sale s = new Sale
                    {
                        ReportDate = record.ReportDate,
                        CreatedDate = date,
                        UpdatedDate = date,
                        Amount = record.Amount,
                        LocationId = record.Id,
                    };
                    db.Sale.Add(s);  
                    db.SaveChanges();                  
                    _sales.Add(s);
                }
                else
                {

                    if (!_sales.Any(s => s.LocationId == record.Id && s.ReportDate == record.ReportDate && s.Amount == record.Amount))
                    {                       
                        if ((_sales.Where(s => s.LocationId == record.Id && s.ReportDate == record.ReportDate)).Count() == 1)
                        {                           
                            var sale = _sales.SingleOrDefault(s => s.LocationId == record.Id && s.ReportDate == record.ReportDate);
                            sale.UpdatedDate = date;
                            sale.Amount = record.Amount;
                            db.Entry(sale).State = EntityState.Modified;  
                            db.SaveChanges();                                                                   
                        }                                                
                    }
                }                                        
            }                        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

The changes I've done was:

change all db.SaveChanges for only one at the end of the foreach, and I got the First exception (also when I group them by 3000)

change the entity state, and I got the second exception.

I'llappreciate your help,

thanks.

Comment: Can you show the exception stack trace?

Comment: Did you try to isolate which one of the three if-if-else blocks is causing the exception, using test files (one for each of the three cases) with only two records for example?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to import data from file to data. If I'a right, I was facing the same Problem, but with over 20,000 items per update.
After some test I came to following solution which may solves your problem:

- the EF is much to slow for mass data Import
- so I used the SqlBulkCopy-Command to import the data in an extra import table and proccessed the imported data inside the database by stored procedures. A method to do Import the data could look like this:

```
private void DoMassDataImport(DataTable tab)
 {            
    var conn = new SqlConnection(this.sqlConnectionString);
    try
    {
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

        using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
        {
            copy.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000;
            copy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TargetTable";
            copy.WriteToServer(tab);
        }
        transaction.Commit();
        result.Success = true;                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Success = false;
        this.LogEvent(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();                
    }
}
```

- the stored procedures can be called from code, if the processing does not take longer than 1 Minute you could use the EF, but if it takes longer you should consider to use plain SQL commands like this:

```
private void ProcessImportedData()
{
    SqlConnection connection = null;    
    try
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(this.sqlConnectionString);
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        using (SqlCommand processingCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            processingCommand.Transaction = transaction;
            processingCommand.CommandTimeout = 10000;
            processingCommand.CommandText = "dbo.StoredProcedure ";
            processingCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            processingCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();            
            result.Success = true
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Success = false;     
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

- using this approach reduced the time for the data Import from more than 5 hours to less than 5 minutes

Comment: I used the same idea for the first time but I got some problems when I pass the data, mainly with PK between this two tables.

Comment: @user2755456 One important point in this approach is that I used an extra table (TargetTable), which is only used to receive the imported data, it has no connection to any other table in the database. The stored procedure(s) doing the "real" import and update the data tables. So the import has two steps, first putting the data from the file into one database table, second processing the imported data.

Comment: Exactly, in fact I'm using this method, but I found some question on my that I don't Know and it would be useful to know:

Comment: can savechanges save the data when I have changed two tables at the same time, in this one, locations and sales?

Comment: this fragment: 
(_sales.Where(s => s.LocationId == record.Id && s.ReportDate == record.ReportDate)).Count() == 1
is suposed to find if there are only one row which match with the same features, but, are there any other way to do this?

Comment: @user2755456 Basically, the EF can submit the changes on multiple tables by calling savechanges once. But you have to respect the foreign keys. Automatically generated keys are bit tricky, the EF knows there value only after savechanges.

Comment: @user2755456 If want to sure that there is only one single entry that matches your condition, you can Single(s => s.LocationId == record.Id && s.ReportDate == record.ReportDate) or SingleOrDefault(s => s.LocationId == record.Id && s.ReportDate == record.ReportDate), don't mix it with First or FirstOrDefault.